# Groovy/POI Returning Different Iterators on Different Systems

Tags: java, groovy, iterator, apache-poi

I have the following code.  Its purpose is to run through an xls file using POI and write all the data to a txt file.

```
for ( sheetNumber in 0..numberOfSheets-1) {
    HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber)
    Iterator<HSSFRow> rows = sheet.rowIterator()
    while(rows.hasNext()){
        row = rows.next()
        Iterator<HSSFCell> cells = row.cellIterator();
        println "cell:" + cells.toString()
        while(cells.hasNext()){
            cell = cells.next()
            allEntityFile << cell.toString()
        } 
    allEntityFile << "\n" 
    }
}
```

On my machine this code works fine, but on another computer it seems to have trouble.  I narrowed it down to this.  When I try to create the cells iterator

```
Iterator<HSSFCell> cells = row.cellIterator();
```

my system returns

> org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow$CellIterator@156b386

Which is what I would expect.  While on another system it is returning the following

> java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator@38fff7

Any ideas about this discrepancies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're running the same version of POI on both systems? And are you using HSSF on both?

Recent versions of HSSF should always return a *org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow$CellIterator* to you.

With XSSF, the iterator you get back is taken from a TreeMap (it's the values iterator), so I wouldn't expect a HashMap iterator but I would expect a java.util one

That makes me think that you're possibly not using the same version of POI in both places

See the [POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) for how to check which jar file you're using for POI

Comment: What a simple solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Gagravarr...you have a different version of something somewhere

And FYI, a more 'groovy' version of your code would be:

```
(0..<numberOfSheets).each { sheetNumber ->
  HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt( sheetNumber )
  sheet.rowIterator().each { row ->
    row.cellIterator().each { cell ->
      allEntityFile << cell.toString()
    } 
    allEntityFile << "\n" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Great groovification.  I've been working with some Java veterans who are a bit cautious of the Groovy syntax.  So I have to sneak it in piece by piece.